# arxiv not showing my figures in preview

Tags: floats, pdftex, arxiv

In arxiv submission after successful compilation, in the preview is not showing figures. There is no information about missing files or images in the log file.

```
\begin{figure}
    \begin{center}
            \includegraphics[scale = 0.35, bb= 0 0 350 370]{trellis.eps}
    \caption{The initial state of choosing the path.}
    \label{fig:fig2}
    \end{center}
\end{figure}
```

the log file data is like below:

```
ps:SDict begin /product where{pop product(Distiller)search{pop po...
Non-PDF special ignored!
ps:SDict begin H.S end
Non-PDF special ignored!
ps:SDict begin H.R end
Non-PDF special ignored!
ps:SDict begin [/View [/XYZ H.V]/Dest (page.4) cvn /DEST pdfmark ...
Non-PDF special ignored!
PSfile="trellis.eps" llx=500 lly=0 urx=0 ury=380 rwi=-2250
Non-PDF special ignored!
ps:SDict begin H.S end
Non-PDF special ignored!
```

Comment: Given that it seems arxiv is using pdflatex, why are you using eps files and not PDF? (it is safer to convert EPS to PDF yourself and relying on auto conversion. Note there might be options in the arxiv processing to have it run latex+dvips+ps2pdf instead (I haven't looked)

Comment: I've converted images to PDF but this problem is not solved still.

Comment: If you're still referfing to `trellis.eps` in the code, and still uploading the `eps` then of course it would not change anything.

Comment: Unrelated: don't use `center` to center inside a `figure`. Both `center` and `figure` adds vertical spacing, so you end with excessive spacing. Replace `\begin{center}` by `\centering` and remove `\end{center}`

Comment: The most common cause of this behavior in arXiv is sending the `[dvipdfmx]` driver option to `graphicx`. arXiv doesn't use this pathway for compilation, so it can cause odd behavior in the output pdf. Feel free to [reach out](https://info.arxiv.org/help/contact.html#technical-queries) with your submit-id if you would like a more exact cause/effect based on your actual source files.